# Make directory inside directory Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, filesystems

I am trying to make a directory inside a directory using the following code:

```
Storage::makeDirectory('app/public' . $data['code'] . '/' . 'themes', true);
```

So the structure will be :

Folder 1 :
app/public/123

Folder 2: 
app/public/123/themes

I have been trying for the last 2 hours. I hope somebody can help. Thanks !

Comment: why are you giving public path, when you have to create a directory inside Storage

Answer (score 1):

You can create the directories recursively by calling `makeDirectory() method
over`File` object

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/path/to/directory', 0775, true);
```

In Your case, To create the `themes` directory inside `storage` directory

```
Storage::makeDirectory('themes', 0775, true);
```

To create a file inside the public directory

```
$result=File::makeDirectory('app/public/' . $data['code'] . '/' . 'themes',0755, true);
dd($result);
```

Comment: In my post it shows the structure I want. The structure for your code would be :

/app/public/123 and app/public/themes

Comment: @TenTimesCake i have updated my answer, check the last synatx to create the directory inside the public folder

Comment: Your updated code only creates app/public/123 it does not create app/public/123/themes

Comment: it is creating in my system, check inside the 123 directory, it creates recursively

Comment: Could it have something to do with the read/write permissions ? On my system it does not create the last folder.

Comment: $result = File::makeDirectory('app/public/' . $data['code'] . '/' . 'themes',0755, true);

I am not trying to make files. I am trying to make two folders with the above code.

Comment: if you want two different folders then use this line two times as `File::makeDirectory('app/public/' . $data['code'] ',0755, true);` and `File::makeDirectory('app/public/' . $data['code'] . '/' . 'themes',0755, true);`

Comment: and also check what you are getting in your `$data['code']`, there should not be trailing slashes in your `$data['code']`

Comment: I get the following error : mkdir(): File exists
 Even if take away the true for the recursive boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the path structure.

The following code worked :

```
Storage::makeDirectory('public/' . $data['code'] . '/' . 'themes');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app check what the path given in `config/filesystem.php` on line 44. So when you trying to create `directory` or a `file` check the storage directory